# PayPal - Best practice for account statement

Tags: php, paypal

I need to import all PayPal transactions (within a given time-period) into my own software. I know that I can download an account statement from the website but I need my software to do this automatically.

Since this is the first time I'm trying to integrate a PayPal API into my own software, I'm quite confused with all the information thrown at me.

As far as I understand, there are three PayPal APIs (NVP, SOAP and REST) - they all offer a lot of methods, but as of now, I'm not able to estimate which API and which method would be best for my rather simple task.

Are there any best practices for this I didn't manage to find on my own? Does someone have a hint for me?

Comment: This question is off topic, but you should check out [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) for the best way to do this

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but IPN does not appear to be the right choice for me. My software will be running on a machine that is connected to the internet, but will not be available over a domain or static IP, so I believe IPN cannot be used here.
Also, would you mind to explain why my question is off-topic? Is it because my title leaves too much room for discussion / the question is too opinion-oriented?

Comment: Yeah, the question is too broad, asks for opinions and is asking for a tool. Check out the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information

Comment: I can't remember if it requires Payments Pro or not, but maybe [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) could do what you want

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll keep it in mind. Also thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Classic API, specifically [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) and [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make those API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thank you for help. It's really appreciated. I'll try with the classic API then.